# How are structs assigned to an array of structs contained w/in a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct

I'm having troubles with this. Let's say there's just a simple struct setup like so:

```c
typedef struct http_header
{
    char *name;
    char *value;
} http_header_t;

typedef struct http_request
{
    char *verb;
    char *path;
    char *version;
    int num_headers;
    http_header_t headers[MAX_HEADERS];
} http_request_t;
```

How do I write a new `http_header_t` to `headers` in a new `http_request_t`?

Comment: Assignment. [structs are assignable lvalues] BTW: what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "write" to it by just accessing and assigning to them like any other struct component. The array of header structs is declared explicitly within the request struct, so they will already "be there" in the new request struct (there will be `MAX_HEADERS` of them allocated whether you "use" them all or not). You access them by index:

```
http_request_t request;
request.headers[0].name = ...
```

If you already have a header struct from elsewhere that you want to "copy in" to the request there are a couple ways of doing it and what is most idiomatic depends on the context.

It looks like this is set up so that `num_headers` indicates how many header structs in that array contain valid data (even though there may be more of them allocated and unused). If you're adding a new one from another header object, you could assign and then increment the counter, like this:

```
request.headers[request.num_headers] = some_header_obj;
request.num_headers++;
```

Etc.

Comment: Where would malloc/calloc come into play

Comment: `malloc` only comes into play when you need dynamic allocation, as in some of this has to persist beyond the body of a particular function or functions it calls. This has to do with local variables falling out of scope and ceasing to exist, but dynamically allocated things persist until explicitly released with `free()`.